# onEndReached triggered before data finished loading

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I try to create PokemonList with [pokeapi.co](https://pokeapi.co)
And i fetch the /pokemon/ first to get the list of the /pokemon/{pokemonName} and then loop it again to get the details for my dataSource as the /pokemon/ only provides name

```
fetchData(){
  fetch(this.state.urlState)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          urlState: responseJson.next,
          totalPokemon: responseJson.count
        });
        for (
          let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve();
          i < responseJson.results.length;
          i++
        ) {
          p = p.then(
            _ =>
              new Promise(resolve => {
                fetch(
                  "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" +
                    responseJson.results[i].name
                )
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(responseJson => {
                    newData = this.state.dataSource;
                    newData.push({
                      id: responseJson.id,
                      name: responseJson.name,
                      sprite: responseJson.sprites.front_default
                    });
                    this.setState({
                      totalFetchedData: this.state.totalFetchedData + 1,
                      dataSource: newData
                    });
                    resolve();
                  });
              })
          );
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

This is my fetchData function

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  onEndReached={() => this.fetchData()}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {pokeNumber} - {item.name}
      </Text>
    </View>
    );
  }}
  extraData={this.state}
/>
```

This is my FlatList component, i figured that the onEndReached triggered because the list is lack of items therefore it triggered the onEndReached even though the first load is not yet completed. Is there anywork around for onEndReached that it has to wait for my fetchData to complete first before it fetchs another.

Answer (score 0):

There was a **discussion** about this issue and you might find several possible solutions that you can apply from [the issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14015).

**First** thing you can do is follow this guy's solution on Github which is using onMomentumScrollBegin at FlatList to prevent by calling without scrolling event.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14015#issuecomment-310675650

**Second** approach is waiting for the data fetching by using timer such as debounce() from [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce). But this solution might not work because it depends on the internet and processing speed.